# cannot import groovyx.net.ws.WSClient from either groovysh or groovyConsole

Tags: groovy

hi  i tried import groovyx.net.ws.WSClient  from both groovysh or groovyConsole, adn netbeans ...

it just says "cannot resolve class groovyx.net.ws.WSClient"

any body gives me an hint?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Groovy WSClient is not part of the core groovy distribution. It is actually a separate standalone library. You need to download it separately and put it on your classpath or use the Grab annotation to download it at runtime.

Example:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules', module='groovyws', version='0.5.1')
import groovyx.net.ws.WSClient
```

Note that this was done with Groovy 1.7.2. Previous to 1.7 @Grab was not available on imports. If you are using an older version, put the @Grab on a method.

Comment: Thank you, Chris!  It really helps - I spent hours googling an answer....seems 2 hours googling is not worthy 5 minutes stackoverflowing!